Calling an authenticated google cloud API without an existing client library
I'm trying to deploy an application on GCP Marketplace and I'm struggling to understand the documentation for authentication. Based on the docs, an OAuth scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platformis required with a link to the authentication docs, however those docs just tell you to "use one of the client libraries"
The API I'm trying to use is the partner procurement API, and while a node.js client exists at @google-cloud/procurement, the vast majority of the methods in the documentation relating to entitlements and accounts are not exposed as methods, with the only functions relating to what appears to be some kind of legacy "order" system.
I'm also not sure if it's even the correct client library, as after checking the source code for it I can see the API host is cloudcommerceconsumerprocurement.googleapis.com instead of cloudcommerceprocurement.googleapis.com
Here are the APIs I wish to call:
https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/commerce-procurement-api/reference/rest/v1/providers.entitlements
How can I call these APIs from a google cloud run service? Is there any way I can use google-gax to call these API endpoints with auth? Normally with the client libraries everything "just works" thanks to them reading auth from environment variables when running in GCP

I'm unfamiliar with the service (API) you're using. You should always attempt to authenticate to Google services using Application Default Credentials (ADC) because ADC simplifies your client code and will run (when suitably configured) on (e.g. Cloud Run) and off Google Cloud.

You appear correct in your assessment that there are 2 similar (cloudcommerceconsumerprocurement and cloudcommerceprocurement) Services. I suspect (!?) that Google publishes SDKs for the consumer flavored service. It's possible there are existing Google-generated SDKs for the non-consumer variant. That said, you can always generate client SDKs for Google Services using either a discovery document (creates API Client Library) or Google's Protocol Buffer definition of the Service.

There is a discovery document but there appears to only a public protobuf for the consumer service. I've not used Google's tooling to generate an Node.JS SDK using a Discovery document.

@DazWilkin You're correct in how I want to do the auth. I want to use the ADC that'll be provided to my app when running in google cloud, however I have no idea how call these API endpoints. I can use fetch, or axios, or any other http library, but I'm not sure how to actually  do the authentication

I can create a client library myself if needed, and there are guides on how to do that from a discovery document: https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/building-a-client-library However, that still leaves the matter of authentication and actually calling these api endpoints. I can convert this python example to JS/TS just fine, but my "methods" will still just be a raw fetch call.
https://cloudcommerceprocurement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1

I've just tried this for myself (albeit using Cloud Run because I had a project on hand). I'll post an Answer with some guidance.

@DazWilkin Oh that'd be perfect! Yeah I'm planning on hosting on Google Cloud Run as well so that works fine

Hmmm.... My approach doesn't work for cloudcommerceprocurement. Looking into it.

Ok, the code in the answers should work.

Please accept the caveats that:

I'm not a Node.JS developer
I'm using Cloud Shell to write Node.JS (missing out on lots of dev tooling)
I don't have access to the Service you're using (I used Cloud Run as a proxy in my [working] code sample).

All those stated, the following should work for you (with some tweaks).
package.json
{
  "name": "78392854",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "google-auth-library": "^9.9.0",
    "googleapis": "^135.0.0"
  }
}

If you're running locally, you can use gcloud auth application-default login to create Application Default Credentials (ADC).
If you're running on Cloud Platform, ADC is performed automatically but you'll need to either create a Service Account (see below) and/or create a specific Service Account. Either way you'll need to determine which IAM role to use
I don't know which IAM Roles you'll need for the Service (see IAM roles)
PROJECT="..."
ACCOUNT="..."
ROLE="..."

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL=$(ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create \
${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=${ROLE}

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

Here's an outline (!) application:
index.js:
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");

// https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/commerce-procurement-api/reference/rest#discovery-document
const discoveryUrl = "https://cloudcommerceprocurement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1";

// Unsure what you need to provide here or whether "provides/*" will work
// This "parent" property changes by the method used
// GET https://cloudcommerceprocurement.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=providers/*}/entitlements
const parent = `providers/*`;

async function main() {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
  });

  // Generates a client for the Discovery document
  const service = await google.discoverAPI(discoveryUrl,{ auth });

  // Revise for the specific method, e.g.
  // https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/commerce-procurement-api/reference/rest/v1/providers.entitlements/list
  const response = await service.providers.entitlements.list({
    parent: parent,
  });

  console.log(response);
}

main();


Though one other question, is there no way I can call the endpoints directly with googleAuth? The endpoints and the host are documented, as are the paylods. Is there any way I can directly call them with authentication? Where I just pass in the url and the payload?

The SDK is an (auto-generated) abstraction atop the underlying REST method calls. I'd question this approach. Not only are you redoing engineering work but you're adding to your own toil by having to maintain this code unnecessarily. See this example, you just need to use the relevant URL e.g. providers.entitlements.list

Ah yeah, my only reason for calling that was due to the fact I'd be coding in typescript. So instead of using methods with no type hints or safety, I thought it might be simpler to just use a typed api "client" to call the endpoints directly, so I have at least some level of type safety

Interesting. Given that the Discovery document represents the types, it should be possible to generate TypeScript bindings. I just don't know how to do it. Good luck!
